# Select column value corresponding to MAX column value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table Person, date is in `yyyymmDD` format and time is is `hhmmssSSS` format

```
ID    NAME      CREATEDDATE     CREATEDTIME
1      A          20170205       135744300
2      B          20160205       113514368
3      C          20090205       163054942
4      A          20150205       135744301
```

Now I want to get count of each person and maximum createddate and CORRESPONDING createdTIME in a single query

I tried

```
SELECT NAME, COUNT (ID) AS COUNT, MAX(CREATEDDATE), MAX(CREATEDTIME)
FROM Person
```

but this gives me maximum date and maximum time from each column, it does not give me CREATEDTIME corresponding to MAX(CREATEDDATE)

e.g.

The query results is

```
NAME   COUNT    MAXCREATEDDATE       CORRESPONDINGCREATEDTIME

A        2        20170205             135744301
```

The `CORRESPONDINGCREATEDTIME` should be `135744300`

Please help me do it

Comment: what data types are the final two columns? date/time or varchar or int?

Comment: They are INT. The date and time are in reserve format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One  more, no joins or subquery

```
SELECT NAME, COUNT (ID) AS COUNT
  , MaxCREATEDDATE = MAX(cast(CREATEDDATE as bigint)*1000000000 + CREATEDTIME) /1000000000
  , CorrespTime = MAX(cast(CREATEDDATE as bigint)*1000000000 + CREATEDTIME) %1000000000
FROM Person
GROUP by NAME
```

Comment: WOW that is a genius! Can you please explain the logic ? I think you have added both and then took a part of date and time

Comment: Exactly. First CREATEDDATE  and CREATEDTIME are wrapped into single bigint. When max is found integer divisions ( `/`  `%` )  are applied to get parts back.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this simply with a subquery that finds the max date for each Name and perform an inner join.

Test Data

```
CREATE TABLE #Person (ID int, Name varchar(1), CreatedDate int, CreatedTime int)
INSERT INTO #Person (ID, Name, CreatedDate, CreatedTime)
VALUES
 (1,'A',20170205,135744300)
,(2,'B',20160205,113514368)
,(3,'C',20090205,163054942)
,(4,'A',20150205,135744301)
```

Query

```
SELECT
a.Name
,b.CtName CountName
,a.CreatedDate
,a.CreatedTime
FROM #Person a
JOIN    (
            SELECT 
            Name
            ,COUNT(Name) CtName
            ,MAX(CreatedDate) MaxDate 
            FROM #Person 
            GROUP BY Name
        ) b
ON a.Name = b.Name
AND a.CreatedDate = b.MaxDate
```

Result

```
Name    CountName   CreatedDate CreatedTime
A       2           20170205    135744300
B       1           20160205    113514368
C       1           20090205    163054942
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this answer,

```
SELECT NAME, COUNT(ID) AS COUNT, max(CREATEDDATE), max(CREATEDTIME)
FROM Person
where CREATEDDATE = (select MAX(CREATEDDATE) from Person)
group by NAME
```

Comment: This is not the result OP wants. Your query will output only one person having created date equals to the maximum created date of all records.

Comment: Yes that's right, I want each persons MAX DATE and corresponding time

Comment: @DineshDB I thought that, but his result does give the example expected results that the OP posted.

Answer (score 1):

Try this also

```
    SELECT DISTINCT
       R.NAME,
       COUNT(1) OVER (PARTITION BY NAME),
       MAX(R.CREATEDDATE) OVER (PARTITION BY NAME ) ,
       MAX(P.CREATEDTIME) OVER (PARTITION BY NAME )
    FROM
        Person
```

Comment: I think Now better

Comment: It is still max time.  Exactly what OP said was a problem.  See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate `count` and `max(CREATEDDATE)` in  inner query and then join back to your table to get time according to max date for each person:

```
select
   R.NAME,
   R.COUNT,
   R.CREATEDDATE,
   P.CREATEDTIME
from
  (
    SELECT NAME, COUNT (ID) AS COUNT, MAX(CREATEDDATE) as CREATEDDATE
    FROM Person
    group by NAME
  ) as R
  left outer join Person as P on P.NAME = R.NAME and P.CREATEDDATE = R.CREATEDDATE
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from 
(
SELECT *,
       COUNT(1)     OVER (PARTITION BY NAME) as count,
       row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY NAME order by CREATEDDATE desc) as rn
 FROM  Person
) tt
where tt.rn = 1
```